# How can I link an object to some dictionary/lookup table?

Tags: java

I'm making a stat calculator (as a hobby) but if use the if-else logic method, The code will be extremely long and complicated.

I am learning java as a hobby, and i tried to make a pokemon stat&damage calculator, In the past, yes i have made some calculators/predictors but those were small, and i have to make this code for 151 unique objects.

I am using simple if-else logic which makes the code too long, i have included a cut short snippet-

```
System.out.println("Enter 1 for Pikachu");
System.out.println("Enter 2 for Eevee");
pokemon=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter level should be between 1-100");
level=sc.nextInt();
 //Also i have to assign some specific formulae to specific pokemon
if (pokemon == 1)
 {
  hp=35;
  hp = ((2*hp+31+(256/4)*level)/100)+level+100;
 System.out.println("Now choose between following moves");
 System.out.println(" 1- Thundershock");
 System.out.println(" 2- Growl");
 move=sc.nextInt();
 if (move == 1)
  {
   damage= ((((2 * level)/5 + 2)* 40 * (atk/fdef))/50 +2) * 1.1 * 1.8 * 1;//damage and other variables were defined already 
   fhp=fhp-damage;
  }
 else //Some moves have even a longer code & every move is different
  {
   usedturns= usedturns + 1;
   if (usedturns == 1)
    {
     fdef= fdef - (33/100 * fdef);
    }
 }
else 
 {
  hp=55;
  hp = ((2*hp+31+(256/4)*level)/100)+level+100;
 }
```

The above code is hardly 1% of the whole, I have not executed the code, but i want to know if there is some method like a database from where you can call out the data.

Comment: It is not obvious what your problem exactly is. If it is mainly code that you repeat over and over again you might try and extract it to methods you can call from different places. If you have a lot of pokemons you could create a Pokemon class with methods that describe standard behaviour and create subclasses that implement special behaviour.

Comment: If you want to handle many pokemon, you should really use a database. Or, at least, a ``Properties`` configuration file. For each pokemon, you can store its statistics (id, level, atk, fdef, hp, ....)

Comment: Yes this is a textbook case for using classes... and all of their variations (polymorphism, inheritance etc.). It's completely "backwards" to what you are doing now (procedural code)